# iOS - How to pass Touch Event to Superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have implemented a non-scrollable tableView on my viewController. On my viewController, I have set up a touchesBegan: functionality.

I want it to trigger, when I touch my tableView, but I have still not figured out how to do that.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: How about using `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to implement action which is triggered on cell tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions:

1. If your tableView needn't to handle touch events you can deselect checkBox 'User Interaction Enabled' in storyboard, then tableView superview will handle touchEvent.
2. In case when you need to handle event in cell you can write such code in UITableViewCell subclass, that search next responder until find ViewController:

```html
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        var vc: UIViewController?

        while vc == nil {
            if responder is UIViewController {
                vc = responder as? UIViewController
                break
            }
            responder = responder?.next
        }

        vc?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```